# How many observations would you need to say with confidence that an event is rigged?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

To explain with an example, say I have a claimed to be unbiased coin. There is a chance that when I toss it 20 times, I get heads each time.

Obviously, the more times I toss the coin, the more likely it is that the total times I get heads will be about the same as the number of times I get heads (I believe this is called regression to the mean though I may be wrong with the terminology).

However, what if I get really lucky, and get 100 heads in a row? Though the probability is admittedly very very low (${\frac12}^{100}$) it is still possible. My question is, at what point can you accurately say that the coin is actually biased to give heads, and is not fair as reported? Is there a certain finite limit, or can you only assign it a confidence value? Can I know what the actual bias is with some certainty?

An application could be to know whether one is cheating in a game of roulette, for example.

Comment: I think you can never be absolutely certain.

Comment: Use the Chebyshev or Chernov-Hoeffding inequality.  In general your confidence interval decreases like $1/\sqrt{n}$, where $n$ is the number of samples.

Comment: You do hypothesis testing. Say you suspect the coin gives more heads than tails, so you do a one-tailed test with significance level $\alpha = 0.01$. Now we reject the null hypothesis if $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n < 0.01$. Solving the inequality gives us $n = 7$. So we reject the null hypothesis that the coin is fair and say the coin is bias after getting $7$ consecutive heads. More details: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21581/how-to-assess-whether-a-coin-tossed-900-times-and-comes-up-heads-490-times-is-bi